# Graph Theory Isomorphic Degree Sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if two connected graphs G and H on $n$ vertices both have degree sequence 1,1,2,2...(two ones followed by $n$-2 twos) then they are isomorphic.

So my thoughts are that there is only one way to construct this i.e a path meaning that if the have the number of vertices then of course they are isomorphic? I feel like this is too easy and I may be forgetting something. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a path between the two vertices $v_1,v_2$ of degree $1$. Suppose there is a vertex that is not in that path. Then that vertex must be adjacent to a vertex in the path. But that would either contradict $v_1,v_2$ have degree $1$ or force a vertex in the middle of the path to have degree $3$. Therefore all the vertices are on the path. The path has $n+1$ edges, using the handshaking lemma so does our graph. So that path is all of our graph, therefore out graph is isomorphic to $P_{n+2}$, the graph on $n+2$ vertices.